# How to calculate the instruction bytes fetched and the memory data bytes transferred (read or written) from the following?

Tags: assembly

For this:

Load b

Add c

Store a

Knowing that:

The opcode is always 1 byte (8 bits).

All memory addresses are 2 bytes (16 bits).

All data operands are 4 bytes (32 bits).

All instructions are an integral number of bytes in length.

There are no optimizations to reduce memory traffic.

Comment: Why is this tagged RISC-V?  RISC V doesn't use 1-byte opcodes, it uses memory address of at least 32 bits, and instruction length is indeed an integral number of bytes, but never an odd number of bytes.  Further, RISC-V would need multiple register operands for each of those instructions.  Look to me like an [accumulator machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accumulator_(computing)#Accumulator_machines).

Comment: So how can I calculate?

Comment: Use an instruction set manual for that processor.  Or guess, like we would.  So, let's say "load", "add", and "store" are each 1 byte wide, then `"b", "c" and "a" as operands are each 2 bytes wide,   So, that covers the instruction bytes fetched.  Each of those instructions then also accesses data memory once.